# How to resolve Inconsistent __typename error in Relay?

Tags: graphql, relayjs

I just tried to implement the Relay in Frontend for [this graphql tutorial](https://www.howtographql.com/graphql-ruby/0-introduction/), In that tutorial, they created graphql server to store URL(Link) bookmarks with the User who posted those URLs.

The relationship between the link and the users is:
Link belongs_to :user,
User has_many :links.

And I listed out all the Links with Users in Frontend, at the time I got the below error.

> Warning: RelayResponseNormalizer: Invalid record `1`. Expected __typename to be consistent, but the record was assigned conflicting types `Link` and `User`. The GraphQL server likely violated the globally unique id requirement by returning the same id for different objects

I'm not aware of how much it will impact the application. because I got the expected result from Frontend.

[Frontend View of Query](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qpDuK.png).

I read this [relay official blog](https://relay.dev/docs/debugging/inconsistent-typename-error/) for this kind of error, but there is no example to know how exactly to resolve this. so can someone help to resolve this?

**Relay Query**

```
graphql`
      query LinkListQuery {
        allLinks {
          id,
          description,
          url,
          postedBy {
            id,
            name
          }
        }
      }`
```

**Schema:**

```
input AUTH_PROVIDER_CREDENTIALS {
  email: String!
  password: String!
}

input AuthProviderSignupData {
  credentials: AUTH_PROVIDER_CREDENTIALS
}

type Link implements Node {
  description: String!
  id: ID!
  postedBy: User
  url: String!
  votes: [Vote!]!
}

input LinkFilter {
  OR: [LinkFilter!]
  descriptionContains: String
  urlContains: String
}

type Mutation {
  createLink(description: String!, url: String!): Link!
  createUser(name: String!, authProvider: AuthProviderSignupData): User!
  createVote(linkId: ID): Vote!
  signinUser(credentials: AUTH_PROVIDER_CREDENTIALS): SignInUserPayload
}

"""An object with an ID."""
interface Node {
  """ID of the object."""
  id: ID!
}

type Query {
  allLinks(filter: LinkFilter, first: Int, skip: Int): [Link]!

  """Fetches an object given its ID."""
  node(
    """ID of the object."""
    id: ID!
  ): Node
}

"""Autogenerated return type of SignInUser"""
type SignInUserPayload {
  token: String
  user: User
}

type User implements Node {
  email: String!
  id: ID!
  links: [Link!]!
  name: String!
  votes: [Vote!]!
}

type Vote {
  id: ID!
  link: Link!
  user: User!
}
```

Comment: Did you solve the issue? I am facing the same problem